# I want to add preloader that show loader untill all assets of component is load then show complete website

Tags: reactjs, preloading, image-preloader, preloadjs

I am working on my React Website.Here is the link of my website[I used this simple set timeout its not dynamically](http://159.65.236.27/)  I used Suspense lazy load but its not working as i want. Here is the link of website that want to do with my website  [Click to see](https://dogevillepack.io/)

Comment: Please provide part of your code which is concerned by the issue so that we can help you with the resolution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.